# Bohr magneton to teslas

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

Now, I'm an engineer who needs some physics help, this document on the cryogenic magnetic properties of gadolinium, terbium and holmium, containsing some magnetic measurements regarding said elements,

> Cornforth, Clarence Michael, "High magnetic field properties of gadolinium, terbium, and holmium " (1969). [*Retrospective Theses and
>   Dissertations*, Iowa State University. 4648.](http://lib.dr.iastate.edu/rtd/4648)

I only need to know the saturation magnetic field of these materials. Although I have an appreciable grasp on physics, some sentences seem out of this world, so could anyone please take a quick look and convert from physics to engineering the saturation flux density? The document uses Bohr magneton and other terms which I know but am not very clear with, so please convert from whatever units to teslas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The document you linked to doesn't quite use Bohr magnetons - it quotes the saturation [magnetization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetization) *per atom* in Bohr magnetons. The [Bohr magneton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bohr_magneton) is a measure of [magnetic dipole moment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_moment) and it is given in SI units by
$$
\mu_\mathrm B= \frac{e\hbar}{2m_e} = 9.274\,009\,994(57)\times 10^{-24} \:\mathrm{J/T}.
$$
The magnetization, by contrast, is a volumetric density of magnetic dipole moment, so whatever conversions you use will necessarily pass by the volumetric number density $\rho$ of your material, i.e. $\rho$ is the number of atoms of your chosen species per unit volume, with dimensions $[\rho]=1/L^3$.

With that, then, if you know that your chosen species has saturation magnetization of $m=x\,\mu_\mathrm B$ per atom, where $x$ is dimensionless, then a sample of volumetric number density $\rho$ will have saturation magnetization
$$
M=\rho m = \rho x \,\mu_\mathrm B,
$$
so therefore $M= (\rho\,\mathrm m^3)x \times 9.274\times 10^{-24} \:\mathrm{J\:m^3/T}= (\rho\,\mathrm m^3)x \times 9.274\times 10^{-24} \:\mathrm{A/m},$ where $\rho\,\mathrm m^3$ is the numerical value of the volumetric number density in cubic meters.

From there, you say you want a saturation magnetic flux density in teslas, which means that you want the magnetic $B$ field, and there my knowledge of ferromagnetism thins out a bit, so make sure to double check it. Generally, the magnetic flux density is given by
$$
B=\mu_0(H+M);
$$
before saturation the bulk of the contributions to that flux density comes from the term in $\mu_0M$, whereas after [saturation](http://info.ee.surrey.ac.uk/Workshop/advice/coils/mu/#sat) the magnetization can no longer grow and you get only a small linear increase in $B$ coming directly from the term in $H$. Given this, the saturation flux density is simply given by the dominant term, $B=\mu_0M$, or more explicitly
$$
B = \mu_0M=\rho x \, \mu_0\mu_\mathrm B = (\rho\,\mathrm m^3)x \times 1.165\times 10^{-29} \:\mathrm{T}.
$$
Here the numerical coefficient looks small, but it's multiplied by the number $\rho\:\rm m^3$ of atoms in a cubic meter of your metal, which is in the $10^{28+}$ regime, so checks out at least as far as order-of-magnitude goes.

Comment: A few comments: (a) I don't think this is quite what the OP means by "saturation magnetic field." This term usually refers to only the *applied* field, the $H$ part, as that's the experimentally relevant value. But the OP will have to clarify for us to know for sure. (b) I don't understand your claim "Given this, the saturation flux density is simply given by $B = \mu_0 M$". (c) Inside a material, shouldn't you use the material-dependent permeability $\mu$ instead of the vacuum permeability $\mu_0$?

Comment: (d) These aren't ferromagnets but antiferromagnets, because ferromagnets' magnetization does not depend on applied field.

Comment: @tparker (a) OP specifically requests the saturation magnetic field in teslas, so it can't be a $H$ field (or maybe OP is just confused; I'm just addressing the question as written). (c) You obviously missed a step in the logic; please re-read carefully. (b,d) This answer is primarily written assuming ferromagnets; if it differs for antiferromagnetism, as I said, OP can take care of the differences.

Comment: Yeah, you're right about point (c), sorry. Although you're right that strictly speaking $H$ doesn't have the units of teslas, in practice everyone I know always implicitly multiplies by $\mu_0$ and reports $H$ in teslas. so that may be what the OP meant, hard to tell.

Comment: When I say saturation magnetic field, I mean the B field saturation, H is simply the applied field intensity (as far as we learn it in electrical) for magnetic flux flow, and not the actual flux density. Also, nice explanation, understood everything first read, nicely written.

Comment: There is a tiny issue here, the quantity x which I assume is the ratio of vector sums of dipole moments to the scalar sum is not really a known figure (at leat to me, do you know it's value for this case of holmium?), I can calculate the rest using number density values from avogadro's law.

Comment: Sorry, mistake in the comment assuming x as the ratio, realized it is the value of Bohr Magnetons per atom.

Comment: @Nirbay Here $x$ is the saturation magnetization per atom in units of the Bohr magneton (i.e. $m=x\, \mu_\mathrm B$) as reported in the reference you gave in the question.

Comment: Thanks a lot everyone, just calculated the saturation field strength of Holmium to be highest at 3.75 T. Great help! (Also yes the answer is very close to my guesse, I just wasn't sure and had a Bach degree paper as proof with some questionable magnetism knowledge, I'm submitting my final year paper for BE Electrical and this helped me with the final piece in the puzzle!)

Answer (score 1):

As Emilio Pisanty said, the saturation magnetization and saturation applied field are independent quantities that cannot be calculated from each other. The applied saturation field tells you how hard it is to fully magnetize the material, and the saturation magnetization tells you the value of that full magnetization. This article only reports the latter (by basically reporting measurements of the effective Lande $g$ factor in these materials). I don't quite understand the article because it repeatedly mentions the "saturation magnetization," but the plots show the magnetization continuing to increase over the whole plotted range of applied field, which would seem to indicated that they did not reach the saturation applied field. (I also don't understand what they mean by "saturation susceptibility," which seems like it is zero by definition.)

For an antiferromagnet at low temperature, the saturation applied field is typically on the order of the interspin exchange coupling $J$ divided by the saturation magnetization $\mu_\text{sat}$ reported in this article, but the details vary by material.

Comment: Quoting you: "The applied saturation field tells you how hard it is to fully magnetize the material, and the saturation magnetization tells you the value of that full magnetization", which is exactly what I need.